# setInterval and setTimeout stopping automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am running a node and express server along with WS (WebSocket).
I am maintaining connected users(ws clients) map and constantly sending some message to connected clients at a fixed regular interval.

All of this works fine expect the unexpected behavior of setInterval and setTimout.Don't even know why is this happening.Earlier I used setInterval, then I switched to recursive setTimeout but the same thing happens. Node keeps on running and accepts HTTP requests on same port and same endpoint as of WebSocket but the scheduler for checking connected clients stops.

why is this happening and how can i make it working non stop.

code :

```
   setTimeout(function run() {
    // call function to execute
    schedulerOP();
    setTimeout(run, schedulerInterval);
}, schedulerInterval);

function schedulerOP(){
    var connectionMap = connectionHandler.getConnectionMap();
    logger.info("No. of connected clients :  "+ Object.keys(connectionMap).length);

    for(var key in connectionMap){
        if((!connectionMap[key].hasOwnProperty('pingtime') && (new Date().getTime() - connectionMap[key]['pongtime'] <= pingpongLifetime)) ||
            (connectionMap[key].hasOwnProperty('pingtime') && (Math.abs(connectionMap[key]['pingtime'] - connectionMap[key]['pongtime']) <= pingpongLifetime))){

            //send ping to client
            connectionMap[key]['pingtime'] = new Date().getTime();
            sendMessageToClient(key,connectionMap[key]['ws'],JSON.stringify({message:'ping'}));

        }else{
            closeSocketAndRemoveClientFromMap(key,'Ping Pong time exceeded')
        }
    }
}


connectionMap : 
{ 'clientip:clientport' : {'username':'*username*','password':'*password*','udid':'*deviceidentifier','pingtime':'last time when server send msg to client','pongtime':'last time when client send message to server'}
```

client code :

as soon as client opens a ws connection , it sends

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({username: "username", password: "password", udid: "dummyudid"}));
```

this is when a client receives a message:

```
ws.onmessage = function incoming(evt) {
                    console.log("data from server == " ,evt.data);
                    if(response.message == 'ping') {
                       // console.log("sending message to ws")
                        ws.send(JSON.stringify({username: "username", password: "password", udid: "dummyudid"}));
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: could there be an exception firing in the scheduled task?

Comment: there is no exception thrown :(

Comment: @dimlucas: I have edited my question with source code
 How can I catch the exception? Neither node, nor ws breaks..they keep on accepting requests...it's just this scheduler code which stops functioning !!!